# Weird behavior of external module variables when used in a threading.Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-module, attributeerror

I have a script that uses an imported module as a config file, and then several threads that use variables from that module, but I'm getting an error I don't entirely understand. I've reduced the code down to this.

Config file (test_config.py):

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

variable =          1
__variable =        2
```

Script (test.py):

```
#/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import test_config
import threading

class Test_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print(test_config.variable)
        print(test_config.__variable)

def test():
        print(test_config.variable)
        print(test_config.__variable)

def main():
    test()
    test_thread = Test_Thread()
    test_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here's the output:

```
(trusty)user@localhost:~/Downloads/Project$ python3 test.py
1
2
1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Pi/testing/test.py", line 14, in run
    print(test_config.__variable)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Test_Thread__variable'
```

So, as the output should show, there's no problem pulling variable or __variable from the main thread, nor of pulling variable from the secondary thread, but the secondary thread can't get __variable from the config script. I can work around this, but I'd really like to know why this happens.